# CodeIgniter, multiple instances of object to array

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

One of my PHP models has the following code:

```
foreach($results as $row) {

            $t = time();
            $t = $this->load->library('Career_Stage', '', $t);

            $t->id = $row->id;
            $t->name = $row->name;
            array_push($results_array, $t);


        }
```

As you can see, I am trying to create an instance of a class 'career_stage) for each database record in a table and populate it with retrieve value.

Problem is, if I keep using the same instance I will each time overwrite all values already in the array.

My inelegant solution is to create a new instance each time calling it with the value of the time() function, guaranteed to be unique, and then to assign this instance to a variable. Hence, populate the variable and put it in the array.

I have a feeling it could be done better... Any thoughts?

Comment: you can call $t = $this->load->library('Career_Stage', '', $t); in constructor of controller..

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar yes, but then again it would only load one instance of it wouldn't it? I need a new instance for every loop cycle.

Comment: Instead of loading library every time you can call common-custom function from library (which is loaded in constructor of controller)..which can return you your required values..this will be good way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

constructor of controller : $this->load->library('Career_Stage');

foreach($results as $row) {

```
    $t = time();
    $t = getlatestProfileDetails($require_para);

    $t->id = $row->id;
    $t->name = $row->name;
    array_push($results_array, $t);


}
```

Hope this will help...Instead of loading library every time you can call common-custom function from library (which is loaded in constructor of controller)..which can return you your required values..this will be good way of doing this..